# Sorting Lists Inside a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have thousands of lists inside one list.

Each of the thousands of lists contain [name, gender, age] with the name and gender being a str and age being an int.

I want to sort all of the lists by age is descending order.

How would i go about this?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the `list.sort()` method (specifically the `key` argument)?

Comment: Note that the very first Google result I got for `python sort` was a link to the official [howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) on the subject, which includes some similar examples.

Answer (score 6):

[`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) allows you to specify a *key* which is essentially something that is used for every item in the list when sorting the list. That key is a function that takes the item as its argument. By default, it is the identity, so it always returns the original object, but you can easily change that by specifying a different function.

In your case, you will want to return the 3rd item in the inner list:

```
biglist.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Note that this won’t specify a good ordering when ages are not unique (they are usually not). As such, you might want to specify a second order, for example using the name:

```
biglist.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0]))
```

To get a descending order, you will have to further set `reverse=True` in the sort-call:

```
biglist.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Note, that doing this will also affect the order of the name, so you would get a descending age *and* name. If you don’t want that, you could sort the list twice (separately; name first, and then age descending), or you could trick a bit: You could assume that no living person will ever get older than 200—or say 1000 to be super safe—So you could sort *ascending* by `1000-age` to get a descending sort on `age`:

```
biglist.sort(key=lambda x: (1000 - x[2], x[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
myBigList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```